# Terminal skipping output following an error

Tags: terminal, macos-high-sierra

I tried to do a little searching myself on this issue, but was unable to find anything helpful. As far as I can tell, whenever I run a command in the terminal that errors, the next command I run will be skipped. A few examples with output:

$ rb

-bash: rb: command not found

$ ls            <-------- this command gets skipped

$ cd nonexistent-dir

-bash: cd: nonexistent-dir: No such file or directory

$ cd existing-dir       <------ this gets skipped

After the skip, everything resumes as normal until another error. I apologize for the likely awful formatting, this is my first time posting. I feel like I am missing something fairly obvious, but I would appreciate any help or guidance anyone has!

As an additional update, does anyone understand this behavior?

$ kj

-bash: kj: command not found

$ k;l

-bash: l: command not found

What I can note is that the terminal is skipping the input 'k;' between the errors. Unfortunately, I do not know how to further diagnose and solve the issue.

Comment: Which OS and flavor/version?

Comment: macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4